# Accuracy very bad in tensorflow logistic regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to write a program that predicts if one has malignant tumor or benign tumor

Dataset is from:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Prognostic%29

This is my code and my accuracy is at about 65% which is no better than a coin flip. Any help would be appreciated

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\wholedesktop\logisticReal.txt')
df.drop(['id'], axis=1, inplace=True)

x_data = np.array(df.drop(['class'], axis=1))
x_data = x_data.astype(np.float64)
y = df['class']
y.replace(2, 0, inplace=True)
y.replace(4, 1, inplace=True)
y_data = np.array(y)
# y shape = 681,1
# x shape = 681,9

x = tf.placeholder(name='x', dtype=np.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(name='y', dtype=np.float32)

w = tf.Variable(dtype=np.float32, initial_value=np.random.random((9, 1)))
b = tf.Variable(dtype=np.float32, initial_value=np.random.random((1, 1)))

y_ = (tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w), b))
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_, labels=y))
goal = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error)

prediction = tf.round(tf.sigmoid(y_))
correct = tf.cast(tf.equal(prediction, y), dtype=np.float64)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(2000):
        sess.run(goal, feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data})
        print(i, sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data}))

    weight = sess.run(w)
    bias = sess.run(b)
    print(weight)
    print(bias)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your neural network only has a single layer, so the best it can do is fit a straight line to your data that separates the different classes. This is vastly insufficient for a general (high-dimensional) data set. The power of (deep) neural networks lies in the connectivity between many layers of neurons. In your example, you could add more layers manually by passing the output of `matmul` to a new `matmul` with different weights and biases, or you could use the [`contrib.layers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers) collection to make it more concise:

```
x = tf.placeholder(name='x', dtype=np.float32)
fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=x, num_outputs=16, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
fc2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fc1, num_outputs=32, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
fc3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fc2, num_outputs=64, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
```

The trick is to pass the output from one layer as input to the next layer. As you add more and more layers, your accuracy will go up (probably because of over-fitting, use [`dropout`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) to remedy that).

Comment: I dont know about neural networks..i tried to do it with logistic regresson as you described above